# Is there a way to change org-mode source code background color with the option `:body-only t`?

Tags: html, css, emacs, background-color, org-mode

I used `org-html-publish-to-html` to publish org to html, and use jekyll to build my blog. The problem is the background-color of the source code part is published to white by default and my blog theme is white too, so I cannot see the white code and I want to change the background color to dark.

I had checked how to change this background color in both [Pretty fontification of source code blocks](https://orgmode.org/worg/org-contrib/babel/examples/fontify-src-code-blocks.html) and [Set the background of org-exported code blocks according to theme](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/3374/set-the-background-of-org-exported-code-blocks-according-to-theme).

At first, these two ways are both not worked. And then the I found out that, I need to add option `:body-only t` to use jekyll, and when I used this option, only code between `<body></body>` can be exported, but the color changed code is in html head.

Here is my org publish setting:

```lisp
(setq org-publish-project-alist
      '(("blog-org"
         :base-directory "~/Github/xxxxx"
         :base-extension "org"
         :publishing-directory "~/Github/xxxxx/_posts"
         :recursive t
         :publishing-function org-html-publish-to-html
         :html-head-extra "<style type='text/css'>pre.src {background-color: #969696;}</style>"
         :with-toc nil
         :headline-levels 4
         :auto-preampble nil
         :auto-sitemap nil
         :html-extension "html"
         :body-only t
         )
        ("blog-static"
         :base-directory "~/Github/xxxxxx/org"
         :base-extension "css\\|js\\|png\\|jpg\\|gif\\|pdf\\|mp3\\|ogg\\|swf\\|php"
         :publishing-directory "~/Github/xxxxx/images"
         :recursive t
         :publishing-function org-publish-attachment
         )
        ("blog" :components ("blog-org" "blog-static"))))
```

And color changed code:

```lisp
(custom-set-faces
 '(org-block-begin-line
   ((t (:underline "#A7A6AA" :foreground "#008ED1" :background "#EAEAFF"))))
 '(org-block
   ((t (:background "#969696"))))
 '(org-block-end-line
   ((t (:overline "#A7A6AA" :foreground "#008ED1" :background "#EAEAFF"))))
 )
```

I want to generate the html with dark background color with the publish setting above.